# Cardinality in ER diagram

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I've made a project that's essentially an online bookstore where one can buy books and place the order.

My database contains various tables like:

- `user`
- `user_shipping_address`
- `user_payment_mode`
- `user_order`
- `order_shipping_address`
- `order_billing_address`
- `order_payment_details`

I tried to construct the EERD diagram for this but I am confused about one thing: A `user_order` can only have one shipping address. I've created a foreign key `order_id` in the `order_shipping_address` table that references the primary key `order.id`. I also have a `shipping_address_id` foreign key in the table `order` that references `order_shipping_address.id`.

When I try to generate the ER diagram, it gives me two different relationships. A 1:1 relationship between the `order` and the shipping address and a 1:M relationship from the shipping address to the order. I don't know how to structure the foreign key constraints because I feel the order table should contain the `shipping_address_id` and the shipping address should contain the `order_id`, right? This just made everything more confusing.

Please help me about this.

Here is my EERD : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your current design means it's possible for multiple `user_order` rows to reference the same single `shipping_address` row.

You need to change the design so that it's impossible for multiple `user_order` rows to reference the same single `shipping_address` row.

There are at least two different possible solutions:

1. Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `user_order.shipping_address_id`
2. Or: invert the relationship (this my preferred option as it eliminates unneeded surrogate keys):

   1. Remove the `user_order.shipping_address_id` column.
   2. Change `shipping_address.id` to `shipping_address.order_id`, so that it's a foreign-key of `user_order.id`
   3. Make `shipping_address.order_id` the new primary key of `shipping_address`.

Note that both of these options are a denormalization as it prevents the sharing of shipping addresses between different orders (e.g. if the same customer makes the same repeat order a lot) though this can be intentional - so that if a user's future address changes it won't unintentionally retroactively update old order shipping records.

A few other tips:

- Consider using `int` rather than `bigint` for your identities - I doubt you'll have over 2 billion rows in each table.
- Don't blindly use `varchar(255)` for all text columns - use it to enforce reasonable constraints on data length, for example `state` doesn't need to be longer than 2 characters if you're storing abbreviations, ditto `zipcode` which can be `varchar(10)` if you're using ZIP+4.
- **DO NOT STORE FULL CREDIT CARD NUMBERS IN YOUR DATABASE!** (as seen in your `payment` table) - This is a violation of PCI Rules, a massive liability and probably illegal negligence in your jurisdiction. Your payment processor will provide you with a substitute opaque token value (or something similar) as a means of identifying charge-cards and applying future charges to stored payment details - the most you can reasonably store is the last 4 digits. Whether or not your encrypt the data is largely irrelevant.